# IIS 7.0 doesn't display custom error pages

Tags: asp.net-mvc, iis-7

I'm running an application that has its own error handlers. Error pages are displayed properly while testing in dev environment (error pages are displayed properly). 
However the same code on the production IIS, error pages are substituted.
The problem is described [here](http://www.west-wind.com/weblog/posts/745738.aspx).

I just wonder is there a way to write this settings in web.config file instead of modifying the code.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Awe is right (+1), but in addition: IIS 7 has special handling described in the blog post you linked and [this MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpresponse.tryskipiiscustomerrors.aspx?ppud=4). If you are using HandleErrorAttribute on your action, this is already done for you. If not, you'll need to set:

```
filterContext.HttpContext.Response.TrySkipIisCustomErrors = true;
```

...yourself.

Comment: What was the reason for this setting?

Comment: Obviously, I don't speak for Microsoft. I can only guess at their motivations. My wild guess is that users consider real error messages to be "scary." Hence, the fake error pages in IE, and this feature. Hence, probably, the pages you're displaying in your MVC application. You just need to tell IIS that you've already supplied a user-friendly error message, so it doesn't need to bother.

Answer (score 8):

Well It turned out that in order to force IIS 7 to show custom pages the following lines should be added to web.config file.

Put in system.webServer section

```
<httpErrors errorMode="Detailed"> <!-- this is impornant -->
<!-- Some custom error pages url go here -->
</httpErrors>
```

Answer (score 4):

There is a setting in the applications Web.config file to set the debug mode:

Default is:

```
<customErrors mode="RemoteOnly" />
```

Try setting it to "Off" (Note: the value is case sensitive!)

```
<customErrors mode="Off" />
```

I'm not sure if this setting is respected by IIS7, but since you see different behaviour on your development environment from the deployed, this was my fist guess. To test if this is the case, you can try to run your dev app from a different machine in your network if you have that possibility.

Comment: I have tried but it didn't work. I also included some server settings in .config file but it turned out that IIS somehow ignores them.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2480006/what-is-the-difference-between-customerrors-and-httperrors

Answer (score 1):

I found out that the `<system.webServer>` section can let the request pass through.  Then, my app can display my custom page. You can use these lines in your `Web.Config`:

```
<system.webServer>
  <httpErrors existingResponse="PassThrough" />
</system.webServer>
```

You can also read the extended version to know [What to expect from IIS7 custom error module](http://blogs.iis.net/ksingla/what-to-expect-from-iis7-custom-error-module).