# Using ASP / VBScript to write to an Excel File

Tags: forms, excel, vbscript, asp-classic

I am trying to take information from a HTML Form and input into an Excel File (xlsx) with ASP / VBScript (not VB.NET). I have some experience in Java and PHP but am new to the VB world.
Sofar I have found ways to get the Data from the GET/POST methods. Now I am trying to create an ADO connection to the excel file.
here is my code so far:

```
Dim cn as ADODB.Connection
Set cn = New ADODB.Connection
With cn
    .Provider = "Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0"
    .ConnectionString = "Data Source=EXCEL_FILE.xlsx;" & _"Extended Properties=Excel 12.0 Xml;HDR=YES"
    .Open
End With
```

I got the connection String from here: connectionstrings.com
and tried to stick to this guide: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/257819/en-us
But no luck up until now.
So here are my questions:

1) Is this the right idea in general? So grabbing the Data from POST for example and then opening a connection with ADO to the excel file and adding the info with queries on the connection object?

2) Any obvious flaws in the code ?

3) Would be great if someone could outline a solution, writing data from a HTML Form into an Excel file.

Thanks in advance.

Edit:
Ok Here is the code I try:

```
Dim cn
Set cn = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
With cn
    .Provider = "Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0"
    .ConnectionString = "Data Source=EXCEL_FILE.xlsx;Extended Properties=""Excel 12.0 Xml;HDR=YES"""
'From : http://www.connectionstrings.com/excel-2007
    .Open
End With
```

Once I call "Open" on cn it gives me a 500 internal Error. I am not sure if I am making an obvious mistake, but since I don't know where to find error logs I don't have a clue where to start looking.

Comment: One more question. I am not entirely sure about the Connection String thing... or in general if ADO is the right way because I have read about various other buzzwords (DSN for Access as an alternative to Excel) and am not sure exactly what the way to go is.

Answer (score 1):

**1 -** If you have to use Excel **as database**, yes it's right. But, if you need a database, should use a database, not an excel sheet.
**2 -** VBScript doesn't support early binding. You should define variables without data type, should create objects using [CreateObject](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dcw63t7z%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). And you need to some changes in connection string (quotes).
**e.g.**

```
Dim cn
Set cn = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
With cn
    .Provider = "Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0"
    .ConnectionString = "Data Source=EXCEL_FILE.xlsx;Extended Properties=""Excel 12.0 Xml;HDR=YES"""
    'From : http://www.connectionstrings.com/excel-2007
.Open
End With
'
' Add new records etc.
'
cn.Close
Set cn = Nothing
```

**3 -** An example to add new record (put the instead of above `'Add new records etc.`) gets the values from HTML Form (post method).

```
Dim rs
Set rs = Server.CreateObject("Adodb.Recordset")
With rs
    .Open "[Sheet1$]", cn, 1, 3
    .AddNew 
    .Fields(0).Value = Request.Form("Param1") 'Column A1 (or with name rs.Fields("col1").Value = exp )
    .Fields(1).Value = Request.Form("Param2") 'Column B1
    .Update
    .Close
End With
Set rs = Nothing
```

Comment: possibly should point out that connecting to Excel (especially with write access if you have it) may fall foul of file locking for multiple users. Also, you should use `Server.MapPath()` to get the actual path to the Excel file and add that to the connection string

Comment: I didn't think of the problem of Concurrency. It would be better to use an Access DB (.mdb) and then export the data to excel later.
Thanks for the answers so far.
I am still getting an Error on the above code, once I tried to open the connection:
   .Open 
The Problem is all I get is "Internal 500" Error. I only have a provider with a folder where I can drop ASP files and then look at them online. Any idea how I can debug? Are there any logs I don't know of? Without error messages its hard to know what's going wrong in an unfamiliar language.
Any ideas are welcome.
Thanks!

Comment: you should update the question with your code if you've made changes

Comment: Hey, I updated the question. Basically it's the same code as Kul-Tigin pasted. But without any error Messages it's impossible to know where to start.

Comment: @MrPink **oracle certified professional** said. You should use `Server.Mappath` to getting physical path from relative / virtual path. e.g. `.ConnectionString = "Data Source="& Server.Mappath("EXCEL_FILE.xlsx") &";Extended Properties=""Excel 12.0 Xml;HDR=YES"""`. And will be better you could get detailed errors : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2640526/detailed-500-error-message-asp-iis-7-5