# Detailed error messages ASP - Showing 2 lines

Tags: asp-classic

I am trying to debug an ASP Intranet application,

I have turned on detailed error messages and turned off Friendly error messages in IE but my error message only shows:

```
error '80004005' 
/login.asp, line 15
```

If I debug an asp.net application I get a block of information including where the error occurred for example, "MySQL Failed to connect...

Is there any way to show more detailed error messages,

I have ran through [Detailed 500 error message, ASP + IIS 7.5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2640526/detailed-500-error-message-asp-iis-7-5)

But I still only get the basic error message which shows me there is a connection issue 'Somewhere'

Comment: I can't help with the main question, but what does line 15 do?

Comment: It means that a database connection failed.  Is your connection string correct, is your database running, (or if you're using Access, does your IUSR account have the correct permissions on the mdb file)?

Comment: Connection string was wrong, new mysql connector requires the Ansi flag, Used an old connector then figured it out, thanks!

Comment: @John, please post the answer as an answer so James can accept it and we'll all know that this question really has been handled. :)

Comment: Still worth adding the code at line 15 even is it's solved by now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Error '80004005'  means that a database connection failed. Is your connection string correct, is your database running, (or if you're using Access, does your IUSR account have the correct permissions on the mdb file)?

(Comment posted as question as suggested)