# display detailed error message on IIS 7.5

Tags: asp-classic, web-config, iis-7.5

I'm trying to display detailed error message on a page using web.config on my remote server on hostgator running IIS 7.5. I've tried almost everything but can't get it to work.

```
<configuration>
  <system.webServer>
    <httpErrors errorMode="Detailed" existingResponse="PassThrough" />
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

When i preview the page i get this error.

```
An error occurred on the server when processing the URL. Please contact the 
system administrator.

If you are the system administrator please click here to find out more about 
this error.
```

Comment: Do you have Remote Desktop access? if you have then you can follow the steps in this link, otherwise you might have to ask your hosting tech support to do it for you - http://www.chestysoft.com/asp-error-messages.asp

Comment: Try making OFF `Show Friendly Messages` setting of browser.

Comment: The point is @John the OP wants to do it via the `web.config`.

Comment: @MrZapzup That is not the issue as that message described by the OP is coming from IIS and is the default message when `Send Errors to Browser` is set to `False` in the ASP section of IIS.

Comment: @Lankymart - Can it actually be done with web.config if the app pool is set to No Managed Code - which is a likely scenario with budget hosting?

Comment: @John honestly don't think it matters as it's IIS that reads the config not .Net.

Comment: @John The [`<asp>` section](http://www.iis.net/configreference/system.webserver/asp) of the `web.config` is specifically for the configuration of Classic ASP applications. ASP is unmanaged so it wouldn't make sense that this was only available if the IIS App Pool was set to Managed. The beauty of `web.config` is you can override configuration without needing to access to the server or even access to files like `applicationHost.config`. Leads itself perfectly to budget hosting environments.

Answer (score 1):

What you have is correct but you also need to tell the Classic ASP handler to send errors to the browser or the default

```
An error occurred on the server when processing the URL. Please contact the 
system administrator.

If you are the system administrator please click here to find out more about 
this error.
```

will be sent.

To do this you just need to override the current ASP configuration by updating the `web.config` file, something like;

```xml
<configuration>
  <system.webServer>
    <httpErrors errorMode="Detailed" existingResponse="PassThrough" />
    <asp scriptErrorSentToBrowser="True" />
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Because of the cool way IIS Configuration inheritance works this should override the default value of `False` in `applicationHosts.config` with the value defined in the site specific `web.config` file.

It's worth noting that in some budget / shared hosting environments where you have no access to server configuration you may have problems setting certain configuration values, because the owner *(Hosting Company etc)* has configured the `applicationHosts.config` section with a value of `overrideModeDefault="Deny"` locking a section from having configuration values overridden at the web application level.

---

**Useful Links**

- [Configuration Reference - system.webServer - ASP](http://www.iis.net/configreference/system.webserver/asp) *(Details attributes and childNodes that can be configured in the `web.config` file)*
- [How to Use Locking in IIS 7.0 Configuration](http://www.iis.net/learn/get-started/planning-for-security/how-to-use-locking-in-iis-configuration) *(An insight into how configuration is affected by locking at higher levels)*
- [Delegating Configuration in IIS 7.0](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/cc627314.aspx) *(Shows how configuration can be delegated to site owners)*
- [Delegating errorMode in httpErrors](http://www.iis.net/learn/web-hosting/web-server-for-shared-hosting/delegating-errormode-in-httperrors) *(This article is specific to your particular problem but might help shine some light on the problem)*

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20475502/internal-server-error-500-w-iis-log/20952619#20952619

Comment: @Zam The OP has already stated they're using IIS 7.5 not IIS 6.