# Valid response causes "Subcript out of range"

Tags: vbscript, asp-classic, ado, adodb

I've got a classic ASP application that contacts a database and receives a valid response but then crashes with

> Error Number 9: Subscript out of range

after exiting the `IF` block the db call is made in. What's odd is that the same code is currently working in production. As far as I can tell they're configured identically (but I suspect there's a subtle difference that's causing this issue) and have identical code bases.

What I want to know is:

1. Where is this array that I'm supposedly attempting to reach a non-existent index of? I don't see it and the error gives no line number. Is there a chance something is not working correctly in the adodb library?
2. Perhaps this is a common problem having to do with a certain patch and my particular db connection library? Have you had a similar experience?
3. How do I troubleshoot a problem that doesn't immediately present itself? Should I just start putting troubleshooting statements in the library?

Explanation of what's happening in the code: When the cookie "click" is received `err.number` is 0. When the cookie "bang" is received the `err.number` is 9. It then crashes with that error at the end of the `IF` block.

```
<%@Language="VBSCRIPT"%>
<% Server.ScriptTimeout = 150 %> 
<%
On Error resume Next
%>
<!--#include file="adovbs.inc"-->
<!--#INCLUDE FILE="DBConn.asp"-->
<!--#INCLUDE FILE="ErrorHandler.asp"--> 
<%

'Application Timeout Warning
sessionTimeout = 20
advanceWarning = 5
jsTimeout = (sessionTimeout - advanceWarning) * 60000

'If the users session has expired
If Session("USERNAME") = "" or Session("USERNAME") = NULL Then
    Response.Redirect("default.asp")
End If
'If the user has just changed their password.  Prompt them that it was successfully changed
If Request("changePasswd") = "true" Then
    Response.Write("<script language='Javascript'>alert('Your Password Has been Successfully Changed!');</script>")
End If

Dim connection, cmd, objRS, latestDate, lastDateJPMC, firstDateJPMC, lastDateWACH, firstDateWACH, lastDateWFB, firstDateWFB, accountCount

Function calConvertDate(theDate)
    Dim yr, mn, dy, dtSplit
    dtSplit = Split(theDate,"/")
    yr = dtSplit(2)
    mn = dtSplit(0)
    dy = dtSplit(1)

    if Len(mn) = 1 then mn = "0" & mn
    if Len(dy) = 1 then dy = "0" & dy

    calConvertDate = "[" & yr & "," & mn & "]"
End Function

set connection = Server.CreateObject("adodb.connection")
connection.Open DBConn
connection.CommandTimeout = 60   
set connection = Server.CreateObject("adodb.connection")
connection.Open DBConn    
connection.CommandTimeout = 60  
'Get Earliest & Latest Date in Database

If Err.Number = 0 Then
            Response.Cookies("CLICK")=Err.number
    Set cmd = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Command")    
    With cmd
        Set .ActiveConnection = connection
        .CommandText = "CIRS_Admin.spGetLatestDate"
        .CommandType = adCmdStoredProc
        set objRS = .Execute
    End With

    latestDate = calConvertDate(objRS("latestDate"))
        Response.Cookies("latestdate")=objRS("latestDate")
    objRS.Close
    Set objRS = Nothing
        Response.Cookies("BANG")=Err.number
End If
```

Comment: For clarification, is there an `On Error Resume Next` before this code runs?

Comment: There is but I didn't think it was pertinent based on where it was relative to this snippet. I'm going to edit the code to include those lines so you can determine that for yourself.

Comment: While you're still debugging, remove it (or stick a `On Error Goto 0` just before the code causing a problem). You'll then be able to see the actual error, where it happens, and then fix it.

Comment: I was under the impression that the error handling statement would only affect lines preceding it. Is this mistaken?

Comment: No, it changes the state. `On Error Resume Next` affects all lines after it, until the next `On Error` statement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> 1.Where is this array that I'm supposedly attempting to reach a non-existent index of? I don't see it and the error gives no line number. Is there a chance something is not working correctly in the adodb library?

This is your array:

```
yr = dtSplit(2)
mn = dtSplit(0)
dy = dtSplit(1)
```

> What's odd is that the same code is currently working in production. As far as I can tell they're configured identically (but I suspect there's a subtle difference that's causing this issue) and have identical code bases.

May be you have different regional settings?

I strongly suggest to you use better error handling.
[Internal Server Error 500 w/ IIS Log](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20475502/internal-server-error-500-w-iis-log/20952619#20952619)

Comment: Awesome link and I'll see if I can get permission to do something like that in the dev environment. About that array- it doesn't existed at all by that point and I would think it would give me Null Reference sort of error for that. Also, the regional settings wouldn't make a difference because the number is being retrieved from the same database in prod and dev.

Comment: @broguesquadron -- If you don't have permission write error into log file, you could just display error on your screen.

Comment: Can't always write to the screen either, depending on the file, so I've been using cookies. Works pretty well.

Comment: Wish I could mark you both right since it was his advice that forced me to pay closer attention to the date outputs. Still, ultimately you pointed out that it may be different regional settings and you were right. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

To debug, please add a statement like

```
Response.Write (objRS("latestDate"))
```

before the line

```
latestDate = calConvertDate(objRS("latestDate"))
```

so you can see if (for example) the date returned from the server has "-" as separator instead of "/" or if an empty value is returned.

After understanding what is causing the problem you can solve it

Comment: Apparently the operating system of the client contacting the SQL Server database determines the format of date you receive. This seems silly but it is what was happening. I feel like an idiot for not noticing.