# Classic ASP - Server Change giving error message 500 when Updating any record.

Tags: asp-classic

I use classic ASP with MS Access Db and have had no trouble Updating records using IIS on my PC and with my hosts previous server. I've just moved to a new server (Windows) and can display and add records, but all Updating gives the 500-Server error. Can anyone suggest where start looking, my script or the new Server set-up?

Comment: What is the new server, OS version, IIS version, architecture (x32 or x64) etc?Maybe edit your question and add some relevant tags rather then us second guessing.

Answer (score 0):

OK first of all change your settings so you get the error sent to the browser.

I could imagine it's a permission issue (write access to the access database)

but to be sure do the follow this guide to set it to return custom errors:

[Detailed 500 error message, ASP + IIS 7.5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2640526/detailed-500-error-message-asp-iis-7-5?rq=1)