# How to see the detailed exception in WebAPI?

Tags: iis, asp.net-web-api2

My AngularJS makes RESTful API calls to my ApiController.

Everything works fine in localhost, but returns a boring and frustrating `{"message":"An error has occurred."}` when testing on IIS Server.

I have made sure these things are in place. There is a good post in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2640526/detailed-500-error-message-asp-iis-7-5?rq=1).

```
<system.webServer>
  <httpErrors existingResponse="PassThrough" />
</system.webServer>


<system.web>
  <customErrors mode="Off"/>
</system.web>
```

On the IIS7, I go to `Error Pages` >> `Edit Feature Settings` >> `Error Responses` is now `Detailed errors`.

How can we see the detailed exception? Have I missed something else?

Comment: You see the message, do you see anything else in the returned JSON?  http://blogs.msdn.com/b/youssefm/archive/2012/06/28/error-handling-in-asp-net-webapi.aspx should tell you what you would be looking for.

Comment: Unfortunately I have seen nothing else. It would be helpful if I can see some `ExceptionMessage` and `StackTrace`, which are exactly what I need.

Comment: What is the status code that comes back from IIS?