# How do I view the specific error/stack trace so I can pinpoint a issue with my website?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, asp-classic

I'm currently working on a page and I want to be able to view the stack trace so that I can pin point the issue. If you go to http://www.phrd.com/cattorney-bio.asp?AttorneyID=569, you will see that it just gives you the generic HTTP 500 error. I want to be able to see the specific error. I remember it had to do with the web.config file, but I don't remember what setting it was. I only want to do this very temporarily and I will turn it back off. I thought it was turning the customeError setting to false, but there must be something more.

When I have a set of code in my page, it gives me the 500 error. Below is my code:

```
<%    
    strSQL5 = "SELECT * FROM ADVISORIES WHERE ATTY_ID="& AttorneyID& " AND Category = 'Employee' ORDER BY Date() ASC"
    set r5 = d2.Execute(strSQL5)
    if (r5.EOF = True) and (r5.BOF = True) then

    else
        r5.movefirst
%>

            <br />  <h3><span>Archived Advisories</span></h3>
            <p>
                <i>Employee Testing</i>
            </p>

                <ul id="ul1">

<%
        cnt=0
        while (r5.EOF = false) and (r5.BOF = false)
        cnt=cnt+1
%>

                    <li><a href="~/docs/" & <%= r5("Filename") %>target="_blank"><%= r5("DisplayText") %></a></li>
<%
            r5.movenext
        wend
%>

                </ul>
<%
    end if
%>          

<%

    strSQL6 = "SELECT * FROM ADVISORIES WHERE ATTY_ID="& AttorneyID& " AND Category = 'Wage' ORDER BY PubDate ASC"
    set r5 = d2.Execute(strSQL6)
    if (r5.EOF = True) and (r5.BOF = True) then

    else
        r5.movefirst
%>


            <p>
                <i>Wage and Hour</i>
            </p>

                <ul id="ul2">

<%
        cnt=0
        while (r5.EOF = false) and (r5.BOF = false)
        cnt=cnt+1
%>

                    <li><a href="~/docs/"<% r5("Filename") %>" target="_blank"><% r5("DisplayText") %></a></li>
<%
            r5.movenext
        wend
%>

                </ul>
<%
    end if
%>
```

And here is my web.config file:

```
<system.web>
<!-- 
        Set compilation debug="true" to insert debugging 
        symbols into the compiled page. Because this 
        affects performance, set this value to true only 
        during development.
    -->
<trace enabled="true" pageOutput="true" />
<compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0">
  <assemblies>
    <add assembly="System.Design, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B03F5F7F11D50A3A" />
    <add assembly="System.Data.Services.Client, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089" />
  </assemblies>
</compilation>
<!--
        The <authentication> section enables configuration 
        of the security authentication mode used by 
        ASP.NET to identify an incoming user. 
    -->
<authentication mode="Forms">
  <forms name="FormsAuthentication" path="/" loginUrl="login.aspx" timeout="20" />
</authentication>
<authorization>
  <allow users="*" />
</authorization>
<membership defaultProvider="AccessMembershipProvider">
  <providers>
    <clear />
    <add name="AccessMembershipProvider" type="AccessProvider.AccessMembershipProvider" connectionStringName="UsersDB" />
  </providers>
</membership>
<roleManager enabled="true" defaultProvider="AccessRoleProvider">
  <providers>
    <clear />
    <add name="AccessRoleProvider" type="AccessProvider.AccessRoleProvider" connectionStringName="UsersDB" />
  </providers>
</roleManager>
<customErrors mode="Off" />
```

Comment: If I take out this code, the rest of it works just fine.

Comment: This looks like Classic ASP, not ASP.NET. What file is this in? something.asp or something.aspx?

Comment: <q> order by Date() </q>  in select ?

Comment: have U created Date() function or is it error ?

Comment: error in SQL cause 500 error

Comment: Do u have assigned 500.100 error handler in IIS ?

Comment: @DimaSUN That is the right question all these other answers about Classic ASP being difficult to debug is absolute rubbish! Make sure `Error Pages` is set to `Detailed` in IIS for the Classic ASP Web Site and you are good to go.

Comment: @Joseph To help you further it would help to know what Windows version (Professional, Server etc) you are running (vista, 7, 8, Server 2008, Server 2012 etc) and what version of IIS is installed (should be able to work this out from the operating system version though).

Comment: @Joseph Also take a look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2765795/692942) how to setup `Detailed` errors in IIS.

Comment: Thank you @DimaSUN and @Lankymart! The one thing I had to figure out was where my IIS Manager was installed. It was on a different server than the one that I was working on. Not sure why, but it was. Once I found out how to turn the detailed errors on, it was indeed a SQL error. Thanks guys!

Answer (score 1):

First of all you are using ASP Classic technology **not** ASP.NET.

Your best bet is to use Failed Request Tracing rules.

Here is how you turn it on in 3 steps.

I took some screen shot for you:

1. Select the site in IIS, and click on `Failed Request Tracing rules`

[image]

2. On the right action pane click on `Failed Request Tracing`:

[image]

3. Check enable checkbox, and specify the path:

[image]

That's it, now navigate to this path, you will find a folder for your site.

Inside of that folder you will see xml file. you can view them in the browser, they use a stylesheet so it is pretty well formatted.

EDIT:

Follow this link if you have trouble :

[Using Failed Request Tracing Rules to Troubleshoot Application Request Routing (ARR)](http://www.iis.net/learn/troubleshoot/using-failed-request-tracing/using-failed-request-tracing-rules-to-troubleshoot-application-request-routing-arr)

Comment: Yeah, I know. Part of the website (the parts that I've done) are in ASP.Net, but this is a page that I did not build. I know IIS is on my server somewhere, but I can't seem to find it. All I find is IIS 6.0 manager and it opens up a window with a direcotry tree on it, showing the web server, and if I expand that, it shows an ftp site and an SMPT Virtual Server. DOes that even make sense?

Comment: @Joseph that is the wrong IIS, search in start menu for IIS, if the second is not listed, then IIS is not installed

Comment: I clicked on start and even searched from the start menu and it only came up with the IIS 6.0 Manager...

Comment: @Joseph you need to install that role

Comment: Okay, so it sounds like I need to install it?

Comment: Okay, I will look into it.

Comment: Go to server manager and install IIS Web Server, by default they are all disabled

Comment: So, I looked at the server manager and the "Web Server (IIS)" role is installed.... I clicked on the role and it took me to an event viewer that filtered for those type of events specifically and also told me which Role services were installed.

Comment: now you should be able to trace error logs, are you able to?

Comment: I looked in the event viewer, but I don't think that's what you are talking about. I went to the inetpub/logs/FailedReqsFolder folder and nothing was there.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/70737/discussion-between-ahmed-daou-and-joseph).

Comment: Don't agree Classic ASP is painful to debug, I debug it everyday! With `Detailed` errors enabled in IIS 7+ or setting up the `IISHelp` virtual folder and enabling the `500-100.asp` you can get the exact line that triggered the error.

Comment: @Lankymart you must be a classic asp fan to say that, I removed offending sentence ;)

Comment: @AhmedDaou Not at all I work in both, unfortunately legacy projects still have to be supported.

Comment: @Lankymart but you have to atleast admit that debugging asp classic is more tedious

Comment: @AhmedDaou It really depends on the setup. Request traces in my opinion can be annoying especially if configured wrong.

Answer (score -1):

In visual studio go to properties and select build and in configuration section select debug from drop-down

Or alternative in web.config set debug=true in compilation tag Eg

```
<compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5">
```

Comment: In the web.config file? Sorry, the answer seems a little generic. Where is "properties"?

Comment: When I go to Properties, I can select "Build" but I can't see anything that says "configuration." Also, I have set debug to true as well, and no dice.