# IIS 8 and Classic ASP client side debug

Tags: debugging, asp-classic, windows-server-2012, iis-8

I've to activate the client side debug for a Classic ASP application running under IIS 8 in a Windows 2012 Server environment but I can't achieve that and every script error is returned to the browser as:

```
Server Error
500 - Internal server error.
There is a problem with the resource you are looking for, and it cannot be displayed
```

regardless the settings I apply to ASP configuration section at web site and server side level in IIS 8 control panel.

Last configuration parameters I set were:

```
Calculate Line Numbers: True
Catch COM Component Exceptions: True
Enable Client-side Debugging: True
Enable Log Error Request: True
Enable Server-side Debugging: False
Log Errors to NT Log: False
Run On End Functions Anonymously: True
Script Error Message: An error occurred on the server ...
Send Errors To Browser: True
```

To test IIS behaviour I simply call this script:

```
<%@ Language=VBScript %>
<%
  a = 2
  b = 3
  c = a/b
  response.write a & "/"  b & "=" & c
%>
```

(note the missing **"&"** beteewn **"/"** and **b**)

getting the above mentioned **500 - Internal error.**

The same code in an IIS 7.5 environment returns:

```
Microsoft VBScript compilation error '800a0401'

Expected end of statement

/test.asp, line 7

response.write a & "/"  b & "=" & c
------------------------^
```

which is what I was looking for.

Can you help me to get the same with IIS 8.

Thank you.

Antonio

Comment: Check out the top answer to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2640526/detailed-500-error-message-asp-iis-7-5).

Comment: This solved my problem, thank you Keith.