# Ajax call causes Internal Server Error

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I make a jquery ajax call, the action method is called and returns data, but the result is Internal Server Error.

Could you please shed light on this problem?

Here is the code:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "/Post/GetFieldInformation",
    data: { feedID: feedID, asUserID: $('#AsUserID').val(), fieldHandled: @Html.Raw(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(Model.FieldHandled)) },
    type: 'GET',
    dataType: "json",
    contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
    success: function (mydata) {
        alert("success");
    },
    error: function (request, status, error) {
        alert(error);
    }
});
```

Action Method:

```
[HttpGet]
public JsonResult GetFieldInformation(string feedID, int asUserID, Dictionary<int, bool> fieldHandled)
{
    FieldInformation result = new FieldInformation();
    string[] feedIDs = new string[] { feedID };
    result.Fields = dr.UserFields(this.RequestCultureID, asUserID, feedIDs, new string[0], !base.CurrentUserSessionInfo.FeatureAllOptionalFields);
    result.SpecificFields = result.Fields.Where(p => p.Key > 1000 && p.Value.FeedUsing == 1 && !fieldHandled.ContainsKey(p.Key)) 
        .OrderBy(p => p.Value.SortOrder).ThenBy(p => p.Value.FieldTypeID).ThenBy(p => p.Value.FieldLabel);

    return Json(result, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

Here is the response text:
�ZmS�H��U�z�u���e��qrxo��b.�����6�2��fF����…�q��\�9���Z����9�i=ȇ���9C�

Here is what is returned by the ActionMethod:
[image: Here is what is returned by the ActionMethod:]

Comment: Debug the call - set a breakpoint - can you get a more specific error?

Comment: Either you're content type is wrong, or your data is wrong. `data:{foo: 'bar'}` results in form params being sent, not json.

Comment: no need to set content type for a get request

Comment: @KevinB was thinking same thing except it is a get

Comment: Still either way one or the other is wrong, but method might be wrong too, ;)

Comment: @tymeJV Nothing useful is returned, status = 500, and responseText has something unreadable.

Comment: Can you post that responseText...it has to have *something* useful.

Comment: @tymeJV I added the text to my original question.

Comment: If you debug, breakpoint and step thru, what line causes the error?

Comment: @charlietfl I removed contentType. It did not solve the problem.

Comment: @tymeJV I don't know what causes the error. The execution returns from the action method without problems.

Comment: If the action returns successfully then what is the value of `result` you are returning? Also see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2640526/detailed-500-error-message-asp-iis-7-5) to get more 500 error details.

Comment: @Jasen I edited my question to show what is returned by the action method. 

The link you provided is about configuring iis, but I use local server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess is that its not serializing if the dictionary is null.  You Might wanna try something like this

```
public JsonResult GetFieldInformation(string feedID, int asUserID, Dictionary<int, bool> fieldHandled = null)
{
    fieldHandled = fieldHandled ?? new Dictionary <int, bool>()
}
```

**Edit**

Try using Newtonsoft.Json.Converters.KeyValuePairConverter object in the JSON.Net library when doing your serialization:

```
  var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject( package, new KeyValuePairConverter( ));
  return Json(json , JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
```

Comment: I know it is not null, and even if it was, the resulting object has data.

Comment: It must be the resulting data. If I return just Json("something"), it succeeds. But I don't know what is wrong with the result. Please see what is inside in my updated question.

Comment: It's probably because your trying to serialize a dictionary, the built in json doesn't do that too well I'll post an answer in a second

Comment: let me know if you have any other issue i'd be happy to help