# IIS 8 in Windows server 2012 R2 to run classic asp and web.config

Tags: asp-classic, windows-server-2012, iis-8

I have an old application developed using classic ASP, it was running fine under Windows Server 2008 and IIS 7.0. We recently upgrade to Windows Server 2012 R2, since that the application is not running fine:

When I set the Detailed Errors to true IIS generate a web.config file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <httpErrors errorMode="Detailed" />
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

After that the "500 - Internal server error" is occurred in all the pages, if I delete the web.config it works fine.

I need to enable the detailed errors to find out what is wrong with some pages, the errors are occurred after moving it to the new server.

Any idea why this is happening!!? And what I should do to enable detailed errors?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: [This question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2640526/detailed-500-error-message-asp-iis-7-5) has lots of suggestions.

Comment: All are asking to change web.config, in my case if I add web.config the application will stop working and produce "500 - internal server error"

Comment: Do you have access to the server desktop?  If you do I think this applies to IIS8 as well as 7 - http://www.chestysoft.com/asp-error-messages.asp .  If you're getting "500 internal server error" it sounds like you haven't set "send errors to browser" to "true"

Comment: Why not change the settings via the IIS Manager? The settings are under ASP, Debugging Properties.

Comment: Also, is the Virtual folder configured as an Application?  e.g. Right Click the virtual folder, Convert to Application.

Comment: Guys, I've tried all the recommended solutions to solve this, but no chance!!! The main problem is caused by the web.config: If exist the IIS immediately produce 500 - Internal server error!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe web.config is part of ASP.Net, which would not be compatible with ASP. It's likely that you were running the 32-bit version of Windows 2008, whereas Windows 2012 R2 is only 64-bit.

I recommend you make a separate app pool for your web site, configure it (right-click it and select "Advanced Settings...") by setting the .NET CLR Version to "No Managed Code", and set Enable 32-Bit Applications to True.