# Getting remote server 500 error on fetching a 2007 SharePoint Site objects using CSOM C#

Tags: c#, .net, sharepoint, sharepoint-2007, remote-server

I am trying to fetch contents of a 2007 SharePoint site and trying to migrate those contents in my SharePoint Online. I am new to coding so I guess I am doing something wrong here. After Execute Query for source site, the debugger returns a 500 internal error. I am using windows form and credential passed for source is `context.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;`

Error:

> The remote server returned an error (500) Internal Server Error

Comment: Check your server logs for the 500 error and let us know what it says. For IIS they're usually in `C:\inetpub\logs\LogFiles`

Comment: @Equalsk... couldnt find anything on Logs.

Comment: Assuming this is IIS you can configure it to provide more detailed errors in the browser. [See here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2640526/detailed-500-error-message-asp-iis-7-5). We need the details of the 500 error before we can help. There are plenty of guides detailing how to get this information.

Comment: Is there any way of finding where the Log file will be located? and yeah its on IIS

Comment: I'm not trying to be a jerk or anything, but these are all readily available on your favourite search engine. [IIS Logs](http://www.google.com/#q=iis%20logs) and [500 error](http://www.google.com/#q=asp%20500%20error). Once you have the exception details you should update your question and it will then likely get some answers. There's also a [SharePoint StackExchange](http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/) that I have gotten help from previously,

Comment: i acted like a dumb... i was using ClientContext for fetching a 2007 site which is not supported and hence 500 error... feel like stabbing myself..:(

Comment: More than once have I wished for a button that rewinds time by just 1 hour so I could give myself the answer. Glad it worked out :-)