# Server error in '/ofi' Application

Tags: asp.net, iis, server

I'm in need of some assistance if possible with regards to a bespoke website we have created and a runtime error that's appearing.

When pressing submit button, we are receiving a runtime error message, but this doesn't always happen. The error is stated below

**Runtime Error**

Description: An application error occurred on the server. The current custom error settings for this application prevent the details of the application error from being viewed remotely (for security reasons). It could, however, be viewed by browsers running on the local server machine.

Details: To enable the details of this specific error message to be viewable on remote machines, please create a <customErrors> tag within a "web.config" configuration file located in the root directory of the current web application. This <customErrors> tag should then have its "mode" attribute set to "Off".

```
<!-- Web.Config Configuration File -->
<configuration>
   <system.web>
    <customErrors mode="Off"/>
    </system.web>
</configuration>
```

Notes: The current error page you are seeing can be replaced by a custom error page by modifying the "defaultRedirect" attribute of the application's <customErrors> configuration tag to point to a custom error page URL.

```
<!-- Web.Config Configuration File -->
<configuration>
    <system.web>
       <customErrors mode="RemoteOnly" defaultRedirect="mycustompage.htm"/>
    </system.web>
</configuration>
```

Nothing on our server as far as I'm aware has changed at all and I'm slightly baffled.

Comment: The message being shown is not the error, but the generic error message. Even if you change the settings to point to a custom error page, this is still not the actual error. Check the event log to see if anything is being recorded there.

Comment: I have taken a look in event viewer and seen the following for ASP.NET Type: Warning Event ID: 1309 Description Event Code: 3005 Event Message: An unhandled exception has occured.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Detailed 500 error message, ASP + IIS 7.5](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2640526/detailed-500-error-message-asp-iis-7-5)

Comment: Turn off custom errors or install an error log package, such as ELMAH or use a 3rd party tool such as raygun.io - You should always know what is happening