# IIS doesn't show error page

Tags: asp.net, iis, windows-8

IIS does not show any error page in the browser even though there are problems connecting.

I'm using ASP.NET under Windows 8.

Here is my IIS config
[image]

[image]

web.config:

```
<configuration>
   .
   .
   <system.web>
        <customErrors mode="Off"/>
        .
        .
   </system.web>
```

I've been having this problem for a few days.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You can also configure these settings by using the command-line tool AppCmd.exe with the following syntax:

appcmd.exe set config "Default Web Site" -section:system.webServer/asp/scriptErrorSentToBrowser:"False"

Please see: http://www.iis.net/learn/application-frameworks/running-classic-asp-applications-on-iis-7-and-iis-8/classic-asp-script-error-messages-no-longer-shown-in-web-browser-by-default

[Detailed 500 error message, ASP + IIS 7.5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2640526/detailed-500-error-message-asp-iis-7-5)