# "Send Errors to Browser" with Microsoft.Web.Administration?

Tags: iis, asp-classic, iis-8, web-administration

I can't seem to find any documentation or help on enabling the "Send Errors to Browser" property in Classic ASP configuration of an IIS site that I added programmatically via `Microsoft.Web.Administration`.

Can anyone help?

It is inside the classic ASP region shown here that I want to programmatically configure something:

[image]

And this is the setting I want to be able to toggle programmatically:

[image]

How can I accomplish this? I know how to create the site, but I can't find anywhere where it allows me to do this.

Comment: Are you saying that you can't find ASP in IIS manager?  It isn't enabled by default - https://jwcooney.com/2013/12/30/enabling-classic-asp-on-iis8-windows-server-2012/

Comment: No. I want to do all this programmatically, with Microsoft's API.

Comment: Don't know if this helps, but if you want to avoid having to open an RDP session you can always use the `web.config` file. See the second answer to this question - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2640526/detailed-500-error-message-asp-iis-7-5

Comment: That worked! Thanks!