# ASP access a table in a database , SQL Server Management Studio 2016

Tags: html, sql-server, database, asp-classic

I am trying to build a classic ASP (not asp.net ) page that can retrieve and insert data into a database. I followed some examples online and manage to connect to my database. This is the following code in my ASP page.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<%

Set Con= CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
Con.ConnectionString= "Provider=SQLOLEDB; Data Source=PCNAME\SQLEXPRESS;Database=testing;User ID=sa;password=abcdefg"
Con.open

if IsObject(Con) then 
response.Write "The connection is active <br/>"

if Con.State=1 then
response.Write "A connection is made and is open <br/>"
end if

%>

</body>
</html>
```

When loaded, the asp page displays

> "The connection is active
>   A connection is made and is open"

Now, i want to create a recordset and extract data from it.

i add this snippet into my code,

```
set rs=Server.CreateObject("ADODB.recordset")
rs.Open "Select * from Customers", conn
```

But, when i load the page, i get the following results,

> The connection is active
>   A connection is made and is open
>   An error occurred on the server when processing the URL. Please contact the system administrator.
>
> If you are the system administrator please click here to find out more about this error.

Comment: Did u click and find more about the error ?

Comment: yeap it led me to a page with some troubleshooting steps. It was too advanced for me to understand.

Comment: In Internet Explorer, on the Tools menu, click Internet Options.
On the Advanced tab, under the Browsing section, click to clear the Show friendly HTTP error messages check box, and then click OK.
Close the browser.

Comment: After doing the above . please re-run your app and see what error you are getting.

Comment: cant seem to find that option in both chrome and microsoft edge,  i'm on windows 10 and there's no more IE.

Comment: @YoongTat I'm on Windows 10 *(upgraded
)* and if you want IE other then Edge it's still there `"C:\Program Files\Internet Explorer\iexplore.exe"` just pin it to the taskbar or if it's not there *(clean Windows 10 install)* [download it](https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/p/?linkid=290956).

Comment: Also this error is probably coming from the server so disabling Friendly HTTP Error messages won't necessarily work instead you need to enable detailed errors on the IIS Server see http://stackoverflow.com/a/2765795/692942 and http://stackoverflow.com/a/2640607/692942

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, if the code you've submitted here is what you're really using, then you are getting a error because of the `ADODB.Connection` object, in the `rs.Open` line, the error description is:

> Arguments are of the wrong type, are out of acceptable range, or are
>   in conflict with one another.

Because you created a connection name `Con` and passed a `conn` to the second parameter of `rs.Open`, that expects a connection string or a connection object.

Read more here:
http://www.w3schools.com/asp/met_rs_open.asp

Comment: Thank you for spotting out my mistake. I am very grateful. Its small mistakes and typos like this that can really disorient someone like me who's a beginner at coding.