# How does one diagnose configuration problems with IIS?

Tags: asp.net, iis, configuration

I have inherited an IIS installation that i'm trying to write a new module for.  My module appears to work correctly when run in isolation on my dev machine, but when i install it onto a test server along with the rest of the modules and sites under this IIS installation it does not work, and i get the generic 500 page no matter what resource i try to access on the host:

[image]

No matter, this wasn't unexpected, i'll admit i'm stumbling around in the dark here so it was never going to be straightforward.  I'll just go see what the log files say...

**Where are the log files for IIS?**

I have found one set in `C:\inetpub\logs\LogFiles`, but these appear to be a record of GET requests, no sort of configuration error info.  I found another one in `C:\Windows\System32\LogFiles\HTTPERR`, which is full of nothing but thousands of `Timer_ConnectionIdle` lines dating back weeks.  I can't find anything of interest in the Windows Event Viewer, either.

How do you normally go about debugging problems with IIS?

(I am coming from a Java background, where i'm used to having the opposite problem - there's usually about 50mb of text files to go trawling through to get to the root of your issue)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2640526

Comment: @RobertHarvey that's useful, thanks.  Now i have some sort of string to follow.  It seems strange to me that the only way to access error logs is view them as the response of a failed request in a web browser

Comment: It's not the only way, but having them show up in the browser with a stack trace is very useful.  Turn it off again when you go to production.  See also the Event Viewer on the server.