# Move code from CDONT TO CDOSYS

Tags: email, asp-classic

```
<%@  language="VBScript" %>

<html>

<head>   

</head>

<body>    

<% 
FromName=request.Form("FromName")

EmailFrom=request.Form("EmailFrom")

EmailTo="sales@trisys.com.my"

'request.Form("EmailTo")

CC=request.Form("CC")

Subject=request.Form("Subject")

Important=request.Form("Important")

Content=request.Form("Content")

myType=request.QueryString("myType")

'CC="trisys@trisys.com.my"

Important="1"

' Declare Variables 

Dim objNewMail, strFilePath 

' Create Instance of NewMail Object 

Set objNewMail = Server.CreateObject("CDO.Message")

' Set Email Priority (1 = Normal) 

objNewMail.Importance = 1 

' Send plain text email 

objNewMail.BodyFormat = 1 

' Senders email address 

objNewMail.From = EmailFrom

' Recipients email address 

objNewMail.To = EmailTo

'objNewMail.CC = CC

' Email Subject 

objNewMail.Subject = Subject

' Email Body 

objNewMail.TextBody = "From:" & FromName & " " & vbcrlf & "Email:" & 
mailFrom & 

vbcrlf & Content

' Send Email 

objNewMail.Send() 

' Destroy object to release it from memory 

Set objNewMail = Nothing 

'response.Write "send to:" & strEmailTo

'response.End

response.Redirect("Result.asp?myType=" & myType & "&AppMsg=<div align=center>

<font color=gray size=2><b><p><p><p>THANK YOU<br>Your enquiry has been sent 
viaemail.<br>We will contact you as soon as possible.</b></font></div>") 
%>
```

Above is the code from `enquiry.asp` from my company website which I assume nobody have check it for a long time. and when I try to edit it, the email won't even work. So I am aware this is because of `CDONT`. So I need someone to help or guide me in changing it to `CDOSYS`. 
Hope you guys can help me.
this is the error that i get after i click submit at Enquiry page on the website
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vy0ck.jpg)

i already try to check the custom error documents button in my plesk.is this what you guys mean?by this message what it trying to say exactly?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r02IN.jpg)

Comment: Please learn how to ask a good question. Thanks

Comment: can you tell me why u feel that way

Comment: I have updated the tags, this code is classic asp and not asp.net. Also, could you edit your question and post the error message you are getting?

Comment: thank you for the respond. will edit it as soon as possible

Comment: @nadia: just FYI, that's a singularly useless error message. You need to [enable detailed error messages](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2640526/detailed-500-error-message-asp-iis-7-5) on the server, and (if you're using Internet Explorer) make sure your browser doesn't hide the useful information in a misguided attempt at friendliness.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you need to change your `Server.CreateObject` statement to create a CDOSYS object rather than a CDONTS object:

```
Set objNewMail = Server.CreateObject("CDO.Message")
```

The next difference is the message format.  In CDONTS  `Bodyformat=1` specifies text format, `Bodyformat=0` specifies HTML format.  CDOSYS does it differently - it has two separate settings instead of `Body`. Delete your bodyformat line and replace

```
objNewMail.Body = "From:" & FromName & " " & vbcrlf & "Email:" & EmailFrom & vbcrlf & Content
```

with

```
objNewMail.TextBody = "From:" & FromName & " " & vbcrlf & "Email:" & mailFrom & vbcrlf & Content
```

If you want to send an HTML message you would use `objNewMail.HTMLBody`.  The other settings — `To`, `From`, `Subject` etc. — should all work with CDOSYS.

One big advantage of CDOSYS over CDONTS is that it can use a remote SMTP server—CDONTS can only use a local one.  You'll need to add a configuration section if this is the case.  You may find that you need to add a configuration section anyway.  I'd need to know your SMTP details to know what to put in the config section, but this tutorial covers most of the permutations:

http://www.paulsadowski.com/wsh/cdo.htm

Comment: thank you once again for your help.but i still get same error.can i know what do you men by SMTP details?is it in the code?

Comment: Have you enabled detailed error messages as @Martha suggested in her comment to your question?  If you have then you should get a message which give you a better idea of what's going wrong.  By SMTP details I mean details of the SMTP server you're trying to send email through - the ip address, port and (if authenticatation is required) username and password.  Whoever runs your webserver should be able to give you this information.

Comment: i already check the custom error documents box in my plesk . i already upload the screenshot of the error. is that what you mean by enable detailed error message ?or is it something else? thank youuu