# Why Link Preview is always returning 500 Internal server error?

Tags: coldfusion, facebook-opengraph

I am sharing a link to facebook, but I am getting 500 Internal server error in Link Preview, I have tested my link using Facebook Sharing Debugger and got the following 
[image]

However when I do right click->view page source, all the tags are there and there is no tags missing

I am using Coldfusion framework and my page link is: https://ok119.com.hk/property_view_details.cfm?ID=87

What I have tried: I copy all the source code from 'view page source' and tested it using the following link: https://ok119.com.hk/testfb.cfm and it works fine

I hope you can help me to find the cause of the error..Thanks

Comment: just to let you know, the first time i tried your link - it returned "Server Error

500 - Internal server error.
There is a problem with the resource you are looking for, and it cannot be displayed." the second time i tried, it worked ...

Comment: theres something causing that 500 error the first time you hit your page - i tried in an incognito window - 500 error - refreshed it and it worked.

Comment: Ok noted, I will double check the code to know why it returns 500 error, thanks

Comment: You can try to enable IIS error details? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2640526/detailed-500-error-message-asp-iis-7-5

Comment: Also check the Coldfusion logs to find out what the error is?

Comment: I have enabled the error details in IIS, but I am not getting 500 error in the first time, could you send me what is the error you can see when you open the page please? thanks

Comment: @RRK I have checked the logs and found: 2020-03-26 06:16:29 103.18.247.23 GET /property_view_details.cfm ID=56 443 - 173.252.83.24 HTTP/1.1 facebookexternalhit/1.1+(+http://www.facebook.com/externalhit_uatext.php) - ok119.com.hk 500 0 0 14069 224 468
What does that mean please?

Comment: @osamashaki heres the error; The key [LANGCODE] does not exist.
Stacktrace The Error Occurred in
E:\Domains\ok119.com.hk\httpdocs\property_view_details.cfm: line 86
84: <cfset mtrStruct = structNew()>
85:
86: <cfset mtrStruct["name"] = mtrNameArray[variables.langcode]>
87: <cfset mtrStruct["place_id"] = getMtr.Station_ID>
88: <cfset dummy = arrayAppend(mtrArray, mtrStruct)>

Comment: @luke thank you so much, your answer helped me :)