# MVC 3 Custom Errors Not Showing

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, error-handling

From a fresh MVC 3 Project, I've modified an Index() action to throw an exception.  I expect the stock Error.chhtml view to be rendered, because I've set `<customErrors mode="On" />` in the web.config.  Instead, I still get the "yellow screen of death" while running from within VS.

```
<system.web>
  <customErrors mode="On" />
  ...
```

My HandleError attribute is set globally from the global.asax.cs.

```
    public static void RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilterCollection filters)
    {
        filters.Add(new HandleErrorAttribute());
    }
```

...unmodified, per the default project setup.  I've run against both IIS express and VS Dev Server.  Nothing causes the custom error page to surface.  What am I missing?

Comment: It seems working with me just the `<customErrors moode="On" />` set, the Shared > Error.aspx is being shown up when exception occurs in the application.  My Global.asax code is as is what it is, I don't have the `RegisterGlobalFilters` method not like your code.

Answer (score 8):

I have seen the same problem, which is due to that I added `customErrors mode="On" >` to `<root>\Views\Web.config`, instead of `<root>\Web.config`

Answer (score 1):

What web server are you using? IIS7 uses a different section of the web.config...that may be your problem.

See this:
[What is the difference between customErrors and httpErrors?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2480006/what-is-the-difference-between-customerrors-and-httperrors)

Comment: IIS Express presumably is a IIS7 simulation

Comment: Yes, I have to use IIS Express with my MVC3 app so that the behavior of my dev error messages is consistent with my production site.

Answer (score 0):

```
 <system.web>
    <customErrors mode="On" defaultRedirect="Error.html">
        <error statusCode="403" redirect="/Error403" />
        <error statusCode="404" redirect="/Error404" />
        <error statusCode="500" redirect="/Error500" />
    </customErrors>
</system.web>
<system.webServer>
  <httpErrors errorMode="Custom" existingResponse="Auto" defaultResponseMode="ExecuteURL" >
    <remove statusCode="403"/>
    <remove statusCode="404"/>
    <remove statusCode="500"/>
    <error statusCode="403" responseMode="ExecuteURL" path="/Error403" />
    <error statusCode="404" responseMode="ExecuteURL" path="/Error404" />
    <error statusCode="500" responseMode="ExecuteURL" path="/Error500" />
  </httpErrors>
</system.webServer>
```