# Custom error page won't work if I set the Response.StatusCode to 404

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, iis, asp.net-mvc-5, custom-error-pages

In my Asp.Net MVC website, I'm trying to get the custom error page working. In the development machine, everything works. But when I publish the website to the production, it only works if I set the status code to 200 (or don't set it). Here's my `web.config`:

```
<customErrors mode="On" defaultRedirect="~/Error" redirectMode="ResponseRedirect">
  <error redirect="~/Error/NotFound" statusCode="404" />
</customErrors>
```

And this is the `ErrorController`

```
public class ErrorController : Controller
{
    public ViewResult Index()
    {
        return View("Error");
    }
    public ViewResult NotFound(string aspxerrorpath)
    {
        Response.StatusCode = 404; //if I comment out this line, it works
        return View("NotFound");
    }
}
```

If I comment out the code `Response.StatusCode = 404;` the error page shows up. Otherwise it shows the default 404 page on the website. Again, this works on my development machine. Am I missing something? How can I render the custom error page AND return the 404 code at the same time?

Comment: Does it behave like this in all browsers or just a specific one?

Comment: @ErikNoren It's in all browsers. I've achieved what I wanted with a different approach but I'm looking for a way to do it with `customErrors`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problem, but if you are using IIS 7 or greater you can use httpErrors in the web.config.:

```
<system.webServer>
    <httpErrors errorMode="Custom">
      <remove statusCode="404"/>
      <error statusCode="404" path="~/Error/NotFound" responseMode="ExecuteURL"/>
    </httpErrors>
</system.webServer>
```

Read more about it here:
[What is the difference between customErrors and httpErrors?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2480006/what-is-the-difference-between-customerrors-and-httperrors)

Comment: My solution was a lot more complicated than this but this works too, so thanks.