# HttpResponseMessage StringContent replacing message content

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I'm trying to return an error message with HttpResponseMessage and all I'm getting is what I assume is `StringContent.ToString()`. Here's my code:

```
HttpResponseMessage response = new HttpResponseMessage();

if (request.Error != null)
{
    response.Content = new StringContent(request.Error.Message);
    response.Content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue(ContentTypes.PlainText);
    response.StatusCode = request.Error.StatusCode;
}
else
{
    response.Content = new ByteArrayContent(request.PhotoAsJpeg());
    response.Content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue(ContentTypes.Jpeg);
    response.StatusCode = HttpStatusCode.OK;
}
```

The error status codes are things like 401, 404, etc. and the messages are plain text like "Photo not found" or "Bad parameters". My expectation is, when there is an error, a response with the status code (401, etc.) and a plain text error message. What I am receiving is a response in HTML with status code 200 and the following content:

> StatusCode: 400, ReasonPhrase: 'Bad Request', Version: 1.1, Content: System.Net.Http.StringContent, Headers: { Content-Type: text/plain }

How can I get the response to contain my error message?

Comment: What does the client code look like that receives the `HttpResponseMessage`? For me, when I do `response.Content = new StringContent(request.Error.Message);` on the server side, I can then do the following on the client side `var message = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();`

Answer (score 1):

You have to add `Response.StatusCode` to the request pipeline:

```
response.StatusCode = request.Error.StatusCode;
Response.StatusCode = request.Error.StatusCode;
```

Else, the framework assumes a 200 OK.

Comment: I added that line and now it correctly sends 401, etc. However, it still doesn't display the message I set Content to; I'm still getting the info instead of the message I want.

Answer (score 0):

Please use this code block for error part.

```
if (request.Error != null)
{
   response.ReasonPhrase= request.Error.Message;
   response.StatusCode = HttpStatusCode.BadRequest;
}
```

I can see the response like this.

StatusCode: 400, ReasonPhrase: 'Bad Msg', Version: 1.1, Content: , Headers: { }

Comment: That's the same thing I had above. The end user doesn't need to see this, all they want is a simple error message. They don't need the version or headers or anything like that. The error message is supposed to be the content of the response, not the reason phrase.