# Passing querystring to Custom ErrorPage in IIS

Tags: asp.net, iis, web-config, custom-error-pages

I want to redirect all errors to one error page, so in the web.config file, i have inserted :

```
<httpErrors errorMode="Custom" existingResponse="Auto" defaultPath="/error.html" defaultResponseMode="Redirect">
```

It works fine but I want to add more option. here is how I want it to be :

Imagine the url of the website is : www.examplesite.com

I want when the viewers changed the url like this :

www.examplesite.com/aaaaaaa

it will be redirect to :

www.examplesite.com/error.html?path=aaaaaaa

I do not know how can I implement this .

thanks in advance.

Comment: did you ever find a solution ?

Answer (score 2):

Something like this should do

```
<httpErrors errorMode="Custom" existingResponse="Replace">
  <remove statusCode="404"/>
  ...
  <error statusCode="404" responseMode="ExecuteURL" path="Path to your error page"/>
 ...
</httpErrors>
```

Incase you want to know the differen between `customErrors` and `httpErrors` you can refer to this **[answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18404091/3793448)**

Comment: Thanks , but as i mentioned in the title of question, i want to pass the bad input to the url as i said in the question but your answer does not provide what i want.

Comment: Have you even tried the code? Because it's similar to what I use and it passes the bad input to the url

Comment: yes I have tried your answer but it shows only the error page, nothing happend in the url .

Comment: Note:It does not redirect, it will transfer execution.  Hence you will not see the query string in your browser, but parameters are accessible in code on the executed url. the querystring is in this format `?500;http://example.com/news/?page=a`  where 500 is the status code, and the original url follows the `;`