# ASP.Net - Cant Get My Custom Error Page Working

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have an `asp.net` website and i am rying to configure a 404 page but i cant seem to get it working.

The code i have in my web.config is

```
<system.web>
  <customErrors mode="On" defaultRedirect="ResponseRewrite">
    <error statusCode="404" redirect="~/Page_Not_Found.aspx" />
  </customErrors>
</system.web>
<system.webServer>
     <httpErrors errorMode="Custom">
          <remove statusCode="404"/>
          <error statusCode="404" path="~/Page_Not_Found.aspx" responseMode="Redirect"/>
     </httpErrors>
</system.webServer>
```

Error page HTML

```
<%@ Page Title="- Page not found" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Site.Master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Page_Not_Found.aspx.cs" Inherits="WebApplication1.Page_Not_Found" %>

<asp:Content ID="404BodyContent" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-9">
        <h1>Page not found</h1>
        <p>Use this area to provide additional information.</p>
        <p>Use this area to provide additional information.</p>
        <p>Use this area to provide additional information.</p>
        <p>Use this area to provide additional information.</p>
        <p>Use this area to provide additional information.</p>
        <p>Use this area to provide additional information.</p>
    </div>
</asp:Content>
```

When I enter and invalid URL i get the below server error

> Server Error in '/' Application. Runtime Error    Description: An
>   exception occurred while processing your request. Additionally,
>   another exception occurred while executing the custom error page for
>   the first exception. The request has been terminated.

What am I doing wrong?

I have looked at other solutions on here and also on the web but all the fixes dont seem to help me.

Comment: I guess there is some server error. Disable custom error and check the actual exception message.

Comment: @RahulSingh There is no info in the server error as i have posted what i get in my initial post.  I dont have any other customerror anywhere in my project as i have looked

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally found out what my issue was.  It was an issue i had with the `ID` in my `asp:Content`, I had added 404 to it (displayed in my inital post), if i removed it or changed it to alphacharacters it works

**Was**

```
<asp:Content ID="404BodyContent" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">
```

**Fix - Removed**

```
<asp:Content ID="BodyContent" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">
```

**Fix - Alpha characters**

```
<asp:Content ID="FourOFourBodyContent" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">
```

Answer (score 1):

Might be an Exception thrown that is not caught in your application (internal server error)

Try adding this :

```
<error statusCode="500" redirect="https://www.google.fr/"/>
```

And check if it's redirecting you on Google.
If so, this is an application code related issue and not because of the IIS.

Also `defaultRedirect="ResponseRewrite"` seems incorrect to me.
Shouldn't it be in `redirectMode="ResponseRewrite"` attribute?

Default redirect is the page that IIS is redirecting if error is not part of the detailed custom error (404 in your case).

If your app throw an 500 error code, you'll get redirected on ResponseRewrite, which the IIS may not find

Comment: I have tried your code and still get the same issue and i dont redirect to Google either

Comment: Could you tell what is your IIS version?

Answer (score 1):

I suspect that the page you want to show as a 404 page generates an exception. This doesn't necessarily mean the exception is in the page itself, it could also come from the Master page the page uses.

You can try setting a breakpoint in your global asax:

```
protected void Application_Error()
{
    var error = Server.GetLastError();
    Logger.Log(error); //This is my own Logging library, so implement something yourself, but you get the idea.
}
```

When this code fires, you can examine the inner exception details and see what is happening.

Answer (score 0):

There are two things you need to do.

1) Turn off custom errors to get to the bottom of what's actually causing the issue.

2) It seems in IIS8 there are issues with using '~' tilda in the path for custom error page please try the following:

```
<system.web>
  <customErrors mode="On" defaultRedirect="ResponseRewrite">
    <error statusCode="404" redirect="/Page_Not_Found.aspx" />
  </customErrors>
</system.web>

<system.webServer>
  <httpErrors errorMode="Custom">
    <remove statusCode="404"/>
    <error statusCode="404" path="/Page_Not_Found.aspx" responseMode="Redirect"/>
 </httpErrors>
</system.webServer>
```

http://forums.asp.net/t/1938152.aspx?Tilde+character+not+recognized+in+IIS8+for+custom+error+pages+in+web+config

Also its worth mentioning don't use both configuration entries if you are IIS7+ then ensure you use httpErrors over customErrors.

References:

[Asp.Net Forums - Tilda Not Recognised](http://forums.asp.net/t/1938152.aspx?Tilde%20character%20not%20recognized%20in%20IIS8%20for%20custom%20error%20pages%20in%20web%20config)

[Stackoverflow - Difference between httpErrors and customErrors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2480006/what-is-the-difference-between-customerrors-and-httperrors)

Comment: The server error i get if i turn my custom messages off is 
> Server Error in '/' Application.
> The resource cannot be found. 
> Description: HTTP 404. The resource you are looking for (or one of its dependencies) could have been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.  Please review the following URL and make sure that it is spelled correctly.
> Requested URL: /Default1

Comment: is that page on purpose genuinely missing or not available?

Comment: The page does exists as if i type the URL i can get to it

Comment: @murday1983 If it existed you shouldn't get a 404 then correct? Might be worth reviewing your IIS configuration and ensuring your application is set up correctly.