# <customErrors /> change Status Code

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, custom-error-pages, custom-errors

I am implementing `<customErrors />` on my `Asp.net MVC` application, so far so good.

I can test it by throwing `HttpException` exceptions in the MVC, and the correct `aspx` page gets returned.

However, i have a `BusinessException` class, with a `HttpStatusCode` property, which can be thrown from the application.

I need to capture this type of exception, and overwrite the Response Status Code to that specific `HttpStatusCode` property, so the correct `aspx` page will be returned.

Right now, even if i overwrite the Response.StatusCode property, i always get the `500.aspx` page.

Is there any solution to set the status code before "customErrors" kicks in?

```
public ActionResult ThrowBusinessException()
{
    // this throws a Business Exception with NotFound status code. Should return 404.aspx, but it returns 500.aspx
    throw new BusinessException("Product with ID = {0} was not found", HttpStatusCode.NotFound);
}

public class ErrorHandlerActionFilter : IExceptionFilter
{
    public void OnException(ExceptionContext filterContext)
    {
        Exception ex = filterContext.Exception;

        if(ex.GetType() == typeof(BusinessException))
        {
            BusinessException businessException = (BusinessException)ex;
            filterContext.HttpContext.Response.StatusCode = (int)businessException.HttpStatusCode;
        }
    }
}

<customErrors mode="On" redirectMode="ResponseRewrite" defaultRedirect="~/errors/500.aspx">
  <error statusCode="404" redirect="~/errors/404.aspx" />
  <error statusCode="403" redirect="~/errors/403.aspx" />
  <error statusCode="500" redirect="~/errors/500.aspx" />
</customErrors>
```

Comment: Have a look at [What is the difference between customErrors and httpErrors?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2480006/what-is-the-difference-between-customerrors-and-httperrors).

Comment: Thank you, but I don't think it helps, i need to "hook" customErrors workflow, which is handled by MVC