# Handle Errors for Http and Ajax requests using HandleError Attribute Class

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc, error-handling, http-error

I am handling all the errors in controllers using the **HandleError Attribute** which i have modified for for **http and ajax** requests, and handling them as a 500 error type.

```
public class HandleExceptionsAttribute : HandleErrorAttribute
{
    public override void OnException(ExceptionContext filterContext)
    {
        if (filterContext.ExceptionHandled)
            return;
        else
        {
            ErrorLogger.LogException(filterContext);

            if (filterContext.HttpContext.Request.IsAjaxRequest() && filterContext.Exception != null)
            {
                filterContext.HttpContext.Response.StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError;

                filterContext.Result = new JsonResult
                {
                    Data = new
                    {
                        success = false,
                        message = "error",
                    },
                    JsonRequestBehavior = JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet
                };
            }
            else
            {
                base.OnException(filterContext);
            }

            filterContext.ExceptionHandled = true;
            filterContext.HttpContext.Response.Clear();
        }
    }
}
```

and using it on each controller as:

```
[HandleExceptions]
public class InvoiceController : Controller
{}
```

I have also mode on the customErrors in web.config as:

```
<customErrors mode="On" >
  <error statusCode="400" redirect="Home/Error400" />
  <error statusCode="401" redirect="Home/Error401" />
  <error statusCode="403" redirect="Home/Error403" />
  <error statusCode="500" redirect="/Home/Error" />
</customErrors>
```

and the httpErrors as:

```
<httpErrors errorMode="Custom" existingResponse="Replace">
  <!--<remove statusCode="404" subStatusCode="-1" />-->
  <error statusCode="404" path="/Home/Error404" responseMode="ExecuteURL"/>
  <!--<remove statusCode="500" subStatusCode="-1" />-->
  <error statusCode="500" path="/Home/Error" responseMode="ExecuteURL"/>
</httpErrors>
```

The problem with me is that when I just uncomment the remove tag for status code then it's work fine with httpErrors but not with ajax request because instead of returning the status code it returns the Home/Error page.
But if i comment this tag then httpErrors not return error page in most cases but work fine for ajax request which i can get in statusCode.

```
$.ajax({
            url: "@Url.Action("SomeAction", "SomeController")",
            type: "POST",
            async: true,
            cache: false,
            data: JSON.stringify(data),
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (response) {
                if (response.success) {
                    catchSuccess("Success", response.responseText);
                }
                else {
                    catchWarning("Error", response.responseText);
                }
            },
            Error: function (ex) {
                catchError("Unkown Error", "Contact the Administrator");
            },
            statusCode: {
                500: function () {
                    catchError("Error 500", "Internal Server Error. Contact the Administrator");
                },
                403: function () {
                    catchError("Error 403", "Internal Server Error. Contact the Administrator");
                },
                404: function (response) {
                    catchError("Error 404", "Internal Server Error. Contact the Administrator");
                }
            }
        });
```

What should I do to catch both side errors? 
Ajax request errors: I want to return the status code
Http request errors: I want to return the page from an action. (Home/Error).

Comment: Please go through http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2480006/what-is-the-difference-between-customerrors-and-httperrors

Comment: I am not just handling http errors but i also need to get status code in ajax request to properly handle errors.

Comment: But as per your code if Ajax request is there then you are always returning Status as 500. Aren't you?

Comment: yes, but it's only work when i remove those <remove statuscode/> tags from httperrors.

Comment: Where you are handling status code in Jquery? As response? what about Ajax error:?

Comment: error is all in small letters. Also can you check by console log or alert if it is falling into error ? syntax for error is error: Function( jqXHR jqXHR, String textStatus, String errorThrown ). Can you try with this without removing remove tags?

Comment: thanks, its working but in response its HandleError attribute giving the 500 Error page. what if i want to get specific response?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it is working I am posting solution as answer.
For above issue instead of checking statuscode check error in Jquery AJAX.
Sysntax for the same is

```
error:Function( jqXHR jqXHR, String textStatus, String errorThrown ).
```

Try to log output to console or alert to check desired result to handle.

And if you want to handle specific response then throw specific error not generic one.

Comment: Thanks mate, additionally i need to return json result from HandleError Attribute because by default this attribute find and return [**Error page**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.handleerrorattribute(v=vs.118).aspx) and i need json result not the page.

Comment: That's what I was referring to. As you specified statuscode as 500 in HandleError it matches your config so Error page is returned. If you specify returncode as custom one. I hope you will be able to get JSON result.

Comment: could you please provide any sample?