# ASP MVC 5 - 403 customError not working

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-5, custom-errors

I am trying to create custom error pages for my application and it's working for the most part, but not for `403` errors.

My Web.config:

```
<customErrors mode="On" defaultRedirect="~/Error">
  <error statusCode="404" redirect="~/Error/NotFound" />
  <error statusCode="500" redirect="~Error/InternalServer" />
  <error statusCode="403" redirect="~Error/Forbidden" />
</customErrors>
```

I have an `ErrorController` that is delegating these requests. When the `404` hits, it displays the custom error page, but `403` does not. I am getting the default IIS `403 - Forbidden` page even though I have set a custom error page for it. I've had a look around and tried to use `<httpErrors>` instead which just seems to give me a blank page everytime.

Here is my `Global.asax` if it's any help:

```
void Application_Error(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Exception exc = Server.GetLastError();

    if (exc is HttpUnhandledException)
    {
        // Pass the error on to the error page.
        Server.Transfer("ErrorPage.aspx?handler=Application_Error%20-%20Global.asax", true);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

U can use new approach for IIS 7+.

```
<httpErrors errorMode="Custom" existingResponse="Replace">
      <remove statusCode="403" />
      <remove statusCode="404" />
      <remove statusCode="500" />
      <error statusCode="403" path="/Error" responseMode="ExecuteURL" />
      <error statusCode="404" path="/Error/404" responseMode="ExecuteURL" />
      <error statusCode="500" path="/Error/500" responseMode="ExecuteURL" />
</httpErrors>
```

httpErros section in system.webServer section.

IIS configuration refence:
https://www.iis.net/configreference/system.webserver/httperrors

And also related question:
[What is the difference between customErrors and httpErrors?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2480006/what-is-the-difference-between-customerrors-and-httperrors)