# Skip CustomErrors and go to HttpErrors

Tags: asp.net, web-config, http-status-code-404, custom-error-pages, http-error

I have web.config settings like this

```
<customErrors mode="On"  >
  <error statusCode="404" redirect="~/404" />
  <error statusCode="403" redirect="~/500" />
  <error statusCode="500" redirect="~/500" />
</customErrors>
```

and for httperrors

```
 <httpErrors errorMode="Custom" >
    <error statusCode="400" path="C:\Inetpub\vhosts\domain.win2012.tld\error_docs\bad_request.html" />
    <remove statusCode="401" subStatusCode="-1" />
    <error statusCode="401" path="C:\Inetpub\vhosts\domain.win2012.tld\error_docs\unauthorized.html" />
    <remove statusCode="403" subStatusCode="-1" />
    <error statusCode="403" path="C:\Inetpub\vhosts\domain.win2012.tld\error_docs\forbidden.html" />
    <remove statusCode="404" subStatusCode="-1" />
    <error statusCode="404" path="C:\Inetpub\vhosts\domain.win2012.tld\error_docs\not_found.html" /><remove statusCode="405" subStatusCode="-1" />
    <error statusCode="405" path="C:\Inetpub\vhosts\domain.win2012.tld\error_docs\method_not_allowed.html" /><remove statusCode="406" subStatusCode="-1" />
    <error statusCode="406" path="C:\Inetpub\vhosts\domain.win2012.tld\error_docs\not_acceptable.html" />
    <error statusCode="407" path="C:\Inetpub\vhosts\domain.win2012.tld\error_docs\proxy_authentication_required.html" /><remove statusCode="412" subStatusCode="-1" />
    <error statusCode="412" path="C:\Inetpub\vhosts\domain.win2012.tld\error_docs\precondition_failed.html" />
    <error statusCode="414" path="C:\Inetpub\vhosts\domain.win2012.tld\error_docs\request-uri_too_long.html" /><error statusCode="415" path="C:\Inetpub\vhosts\domain.win2012.tld\error_docs\unsupported_media_type.html" />
    <remove statusCode="500" subStatusCode="-1" /><error statusCode="500" path="C:\Inetpub\vhosts\domain.win2012.tld\error_docs\internal_server_error.html" />
    <remove statusCode="501" subStatusCode="-1" /><error statusCode="501" path="C:\Inetpub\vhosts\domain.win2012.tld\error_docs\not_implemented.html" />
    <remove statusCode="502" subStatusCode="-1" /><error statusCode="502" path="C:\Inetpub\vhosts\domain.win2012.tld\error_docs\bad_gateway.html" />
    <error statusCode="503" path="C:\Inetpub\vhosts\domain.win2012.tld\error_docs\maintenance.html" />
</httpErrors>
```

On 404 Error. Skipping 404 page and goes to .aspxerrorpath= page.aspx
and writing 
**The resource you are looking for has been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.**

I want to show my customized 404, 500 error page. What is the wrong

Comment: Remove absolute paths. Add custom error pages to you default root directory of your project and then add relative paths. This should work.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that if you create a 404.html file and put it in your root folder, it should pick it up.

Answer (score 1):

In short, in production it is possible to completely get rid of the "system.web -> customErrors" section, which is almost kept for the compatibility purposes (check the [What is the difference between customErrors and httpErrors?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2480006/) thread to learn more), and where you also specify redirects. Then, specify the necessary redirects and custom error pages within the "system.webServer -> httpErrors" section only. Make sure that these HTML files exist on the web server and are available via the relative paths (or these pages exist inside one of a parent web app on the same web server, so that these "errors" settings are inherited).

Solution Explorer:

~/YourWebApp

- ...
- not_found.html
- Web.config

Web.config (for the 404 status code error):

```
<!--Dev: For Visual Studio Mode-->
<system.web>
  <customErrors mode="On">
    <error statusCode="404" redirect="~/not_found.html" />
  </customErrors>
</system.web>


<!--Prod: For IIS Mode-->
<system.webServer>
  <httpErrors errorMode="Custom">
    <!--<error statusCode="404" path="C:\Inetpub\vhosts\domain.win2012.tld\error_docs\not_found.html" />-->
    <error statusCode="404" path="~/not_found.html" responseMode="Redirect" />
  </httpErrors>
</system.webServer>
```

Comment: For 404 status, it works. But 500 is going 404 page. Why ?