# How do I debug .net IIS custom HTTP errors locally

Tags: asp.net-mvc, debugging, iis, custom-error-pages

I want to debug the controller that handles all HTTP errors in the site. There is the following in the web.config

```
<httpErrors errorMode="Custom" existingResponse="Replace">
  <remove statusCode="404" />
  <error statusCode="404" responseMode="ExecuteURL" path="/Error/NotFound" />
  <remove statusCode="500" />
  <error statusCode="500" responseMode="ExecuteURL" path="/Error/ServerError" />
</httpErrors>
```

But when I deliberately throw an exception

```
throw new HttpException(500, "error, I cant be bothered");
```

The controller for `Error/ServerError` is not hit and I get the standard yellow detailed error page.

[image: Yellow detailed error screen]

The documentation states

> If you set the errorMode value to Custom, IIS returns only custom
>   error messages to all requesting browsers.

- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/configuration/system.webserver/httperrors/

Which should mean local errors are handled by the custom pages.

What other settings affect the display of detailed error message? What can I change to get the custom error page to display locally?

Thanks

Comment: The issue may be thorny, depending on which version of IIS or VS Dev server you're using, whether it's asp.net or IIS native, etc..  This link may help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2480006/what-is-the-difference-between-customerrors-and-httperrors

Comment: I'm using IIS 7.5

Comment: You could try the customErrors element instead