# Show friendly error page for dangerous request

Tags: asp.net, iis-8

My ASP .Net website's web.config is configured as

```
  <system.web>
   .....
    <customErrors mode="RemoteOnly">
      <error statusCode="500" redirect="/500/" />
    </customErrors>

  <system.webServer>
    ....
    <httpErrors>
      <remove statusCode="400" subStatusCode="-1" />
      <remove statusCode="401" subStatusCode="-1" />
      <remove statusCode="403" subStatusCode="-1" />
      <remove statusCode="404" subStatusCode="-1" />
      <remove statusCode="500" subStatusCode="-1" />
      <error statusCode="400" path="/404/" responseMode="Redirect" />
      <error statusCode="401" path="/404/" responseMode="Redirect" />
      <error statusCode="403" path="/404/" responseMode="ExecuteURL" />
      <error statusCode="404" path="/404/" responseMode="ExecuteURL" />
      <error statusCode="500" path="/500/" responseMode="ExecuteURL" />
    </httpErrors>
```

I test a 404 page and my friendly error page displays but when i add < to the URL which i believe returns a 400 response i just get the YSOD (Yellow screen of death) instead of the expected friendly page?

What have i missed off?

Comment: I've tried to fix this for ages with no luck. I get a server 404 though, not the ysod. Test with debugging off, not that it will fix it.

Comment: Your right it won't fix it as it just gives the error....

Answer (score 0):

Adding ‘<’ to the URL causes the Dotnet Code error, which can be captured by the custom error feature.

```
<customErrors mode="On" defaultRedirect="/MyError1.html" redirectMode="ResponseRedirect">
    <error statusCode="400" redirect="/MyError400.html" />
    <!--<error statusCode="401" redirect="/MyError2.html" />
    <error statusCode="403" redirect="/MyError2.html" />
    <error statusCode="404" redirect="/MyError2.html" />
    <error statusCode="500" redirect="/MyError2.html" />-->
  </customErrors>
```

On my side, I usually combine the `custom error` feature with the `http error` feature to handle the errors since both the IIS and DotNet code may throw an exception. It also can avert the `YSOD`.

```
<customErrors mode="On" defaultRedirect="/MyError1.html" redirectMode="ResponseRedirect">
    <error statusCode="400" redirect="/MyError400.html" />
    <!--<error statusCode="401" redirect="/MyError2.html" />
    <error statusCode="403" redirect="/MyError2.html" />
    <error statusCode="404" redirect="/MyError2.html" />
    <error statusCode="500" redirect="/MyError2.html" />-->
  </customErrors>
  </system.web>
  <system.webServer>
    <httpErrors errorMode="Custom" existingResponse="Auto">
      <remove statusCode="400" />
      <remove statusCode="401" />
      <remove statusCode="403" />
      <remove statusCode="404" />
      <remove statusCode="500" />
      <error statusCode="400" path="MyError.html" responseMode="File" />
      <error statusCode="401" path="MyError.html" responseMode="File" />
      <error statusCode="403" path="MyError.html" responseMode="File" />
      <error statusCode="404" path="MyError.html" responseMode="File" />
      <error statusCode="500" path="MyError.html" responseMode="File" />
    </httpErrors>
  </system.webServer>
```

Result.
[image]
For more details.
[What is the difference between customErrors and httpErrors?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2480006/what-is-the-difference-between-customerrors-and-httperrors)
Feel free to let me know if there is anything I can help with.